# Sweep collision between two moving spheres?

Tags: xna, c#, collision-detection, sphere

Say I have a scenario like this:
[image: Scenario]

Here I got two spheres (sphere A and B) that moves from on spot to another during a frame.
How can I predict where these two collide if they collide at all? In between these frames?

I tried to look it up and found [this page](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131790/simple_intersection_tests_for_games.php?page=2), but I didn't understand much of it. Could someone try to explain this to me? I'm coding this in C# with XNA and I've been stuck with this issue for a very long time now

Comment: I found a great explination of my problem [here!](http://twobitcoder.blogspot.be/2010/04/circle-collision-detection.html) This article even came with an great example in XNA, I recommend people with the same problem to read it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a good algorithm to detect collision between moving spheres?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/313/what-is-a-good-algorithm-to-detect-collision-between-moving-spheres)

Answer (score 1):

Explaining the [provided link](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131790/simple_intersection_tests_for_games.php?page=2):

The linear segments

`A(u) = A0 + u * Va`

and

`B(u) = B0 + u * Vb`

are just parametric representations of the segments `Va = (A0, A1)` and `Vb = (B0, B1)`. You should recall that the vector can be represented by the difference of the end points. That's why `Va = A1 - A0` and `Vb = B1 - B0`.

`A(u)` and `B(u)` are said to be parametric because as you vary the parameter `u` from `0` to `1` you get points `A(u)` or `B(u)` that will build the segment `Va` or `Vb` (respectively) from the starting point `A0` or `B0` (respectively) to the the end point `A1` or `B1` (respectively). You can see that by thinking of the cases where `u = 0, where A(u) = A0 and B(u) = B0` (starting points) and where `u = 1, where A(u) = A1 and B(u) = B1` (end points). Any value of `u` between `0` and `1` will result in points between `A0` and `A1` or `B0` and `B1` (respectively).

The expression

`( B(u) - A(u) )* ( B(u) - A(u) )`

is just the dot product of the vector that represents the distance of the points `B(u)` and `A(u)` with itself. The formula of the squared distance between two points is

`d^2[ A(u), B(u) ] = ( xA(u) - xB(u) )^2 + ( yA(u) - yB(u) )^2`

Derivation come from the Pythagorian theorem and [can be seen here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html). By the definition of the dot product, we see that

`( B(u) - A(u) ) * ( B(u) - A(u) ) = d^2[ A(u), B(u) ]`

, since the dot product sums the product of the components of the vector.

The last statement of the article is that when the collision occurs

`[ B(u) - A(u) ] * [ B(u) - A(u) ] = ( ra + rb ) ^ 2`

where ra and rb are the radii of the spheres. What this expression means is that the first time of collision occurs when the distance between `A(u)` and `B(u)` is equals to the distance between the centers of the spheres. This is true because `ra + rb` represents the distance of the centers when the spheres are side-by-side. It is squared just because the other side of the equation also is, so they are in the same measuring unit.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the [frame of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_of_reference) and *everything* will become wonderfully simple.

You currently have:

- sphere A (position `Pa`, velocity `Va`, radius `Ra`)
- sphere B (position `Pb`, velocity `Vb`, radius `Rb`)

In terms of collision detection, this is equivalent to:

- sphere A' (position at origin, velocity zero, radius `Ra + Rb`)
- point B' (position `Pb - Pa`, velocity `Vb - Va`)

Now you just need to check whether (and when) the **point** hits the **sphere**. This becomes a simple [segment/sphere intersection test](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/index.html#linesphere). If there is a collision, the change in the frame of reference doesn’t affect the collision time `t_coll`. You can then compute the new positions of the two original spheres: `Pa + Va * t_coll` and `Pb + Vb * t_coll`.